# How can I prevent the benepar parser from splitting a specific substring when parsing a string?

Tags: python, nlp, tokenize, parse-tree, benepar

I use the [benepar parser](https://github.com/nikitakit/self-attentive-parser) to parse sentences into trees. How can I prevent the benepar parser from splitting a specific substring when parsing a string?

E.g., the token `gonna` is split by benepar into two tokens `gon` and `na`, which I don't want.

---

Code example, with pre-requisites:

```
pip install spacy benepar
python -m nltk.downloader punkt benepar_en3
python -m spacy download en_core_web_md
```

If I run:

```py
import benepar, spacy
import nltk
benepar.download('benepar_en3')
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_md')
if spacy.__version__.startswith('2'):
    nlp.add_pipe(benepar.BeneparComponent("benepar_en3"))
else:
    nlp.add_pipe("benepar", config={"model": "benepar_en3"})
doc = nlp("This is gonna be fun.")
sent = list(doc.sents)[0]
print(sent._.parse_string)
```

It'll output:

```
(S (NP (DT This)) (VP (VBZ is) (VP (TO gon) (VP (TO na) (VP (VB be) (NP (NN fun)))))) (. .))
```

The issue is that the token `gonna` is split into two tokens `gon` and `na`. How can I prevent that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `nlp.tokenizer.add_special_case`:

```
import benepar, spacy
import nltk
benepar.download('benepar_en3')
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_md')
from spacy.symbols import ORTH
nlp.tokenizer.add_special_case(u'gonna', [{ORTH: u'gonna'}])
if spacy.__version__.startswith('2'):
    nlp.add_pipe(benepar.BeneparComponent("benepar_en3"))
else:
    nlp.add_pipe("benepar", config={"model": "benepar_en3"})
doc = nlp("This is gonna be fun.")
sent = list(doc.sents)[0]
print(sent._.parse_string)
```

Output:

```
(S (NP (DT This)) (VP (VBZ is) (VP (TO gonna) (VP (VB be) (NP (NN fun))))) (. .))
```